# how do I apply the stereo effect to a video mapped sphere?`

Tags: three.js, stereo-3d, google-cardboard, oculus

Assuming all my assets are linked properly. Using the oculusRiftEffect.js or the StereoEffect.js - how can I make my html file cardboard compatible? My Gist link is below

https://gist.github.com/4d9e4c81a6b13874ed52.git

Please advise

Comment: propper link: https://gist.github.com/tjddizon/4d9e4c81a6b13874ed52

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what are you trying to do? "Stereo effect" isn't very descriptive.
However assuming that you have stereo video files (one for left eye, one for right eye) you'd just play them back in a left sphere (seen by the left eye), and a right sphere for the right eye. The spheres are offset by the interpupillary distance (IPD) - usually about 55mm. (it'd actually be whatever the stereo videos are offset by).

So, you might ask - what happens when I turn around? The IPD goes negative. When I look up or down? It goes to zero. Welcome to stereo video. 
Note that there are ways around this, but you're not going to get them with a GoPro without a lot of special processing. At best you can sync the IDP direction with the averaged lens separation for the video streams, but you'll always get stitching errors. The equirectangular format (i.e square video) isn't the best, you'll always get the wrong answer at the poles. Not using a sphere is probably how it will evolve (but it's the simplest solution till we get a better one)

But, given all that, give it a shot, the brain is very forgiving - and it'll look 3D-ish most of the time. This stuff is being refined all the time.